# What does B need to say about the position of A in the drawing?

Tags: sentence

Something like (I guess): Stand ... (not forward/not backward) ... the tree.
I can't figure out how to express in English the position of A.

[image]

Comment: Ng. is this a game? Is B a person? Bear in mind that level with the tree could be to the left or to the right.

Comment: Yes, it is a game. As others suggested, we should add "in the middle of the field, level with the tree".

Comment: Yes, it is a game. As others suggested, we should add "in the middle of the field, level with the tree". In the game, "in the middle of the field" can be implied by B poiting at the direction in front of B. What I need is the position in the direction perpendicular to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Level with the tree"  would work for me.  It depends on there being an understood "forward/backward" axis implied by the direction of the game.

Comment: Great, "level with" is what I need.

Comment: level with the tree is fine for descriptions but I doubt B would **say** that to A. Also, level with the tree can be either side of the tree. So, I don't see that it solves anything. It would be nice is the OP were more explicit about his needs.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough.  How can B describe the position of A?  Now I doubt that B would need to describe then position, but a coach at B might say to a player "Stand level with the tree, and don't come forward until the ball comes into your half."  I think "level with" answers this questino.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "stand **in line**" with the tree, or "stand **as far back/forward**" as the tree. Both of these rely quite a bit on the context of the field lines, and some domain knowledge that in most games, it's the front-to-back positioning of players that tends most important from a rules perspective.

Comment: No, stand in line with the tree is not right here.

Comment: @Lambie Sure it is. If I told you to "stand in line" with a person, there are only really two logical options, either stand in front/back of them, or to their side. There are of course infinite lines you could draw from the tree to stand in line with, but only one logical choice which intersects the field you're playing on. The *only* line that can be drawn from the tree to the field which has a meaningful relationship with the field itself its the line parallel to the end lines.

Answer (score 2):

B, who is from Ohio, says the following to A, who is also from Ohio:

> Stand in the middle of the field across from the tree and I'll kick the ball to you.

There are a surprisingly limited number of options when trying to communicate this (in Ohio).  No one says *level with the tree* here.

Answer (score 0):

A is standing **to one side of the tree.**

A is standing **to the left of the tree.**

*This is an interesting question since I understand that some Asian languages deal with space in a very different way.*

B is above the line.
A is below the line.
The tree is outside the line to the left.

B says (looking down) that A is to the right of three. However, this is not a map, so it's best to assume that B is looking straight at the picture like we are.

For information, this is about deixis in English.

Read about that here: [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis)

Comment: One could also say *across from the tree* or *next to the tree.*

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther The car was across from the house. But here, I would not say across from.

Comment: If you are observing from the perspective of B, as indicated in the question, A is standing to the right of the tree.

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther B needs to say that A is standing to the left of the tree. Of course, if you are B and looking down, it's to the right.

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying.  **If you are B looking at A, A is to the right of the tree.** If you are observing god-like from above, A is to the left of the tree.  The question asks, **What does B say about A....**

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther There are in fact three vantage points. The most common however for us looking at that is to the left. If you are a viewer trying to see how B sees A, you have to flip yourself up and then down to stand where B is standing. Then, A is to the right of the tree. Also, you can imagine B to be above A, and A is still to the right.